# Union All have mismatched column count

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to union some table. But I am having some issues with the query as I have the following error:
Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count; query 1 has 10 columns, query 2 has 12 columns at [3:1]

The query used is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * ,null, FROM   `table_2`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM   `table_3`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM   `table_4`
UNION ALL
SELECT * , null, FROM   `table_5`
```

Please someone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your full query as there is a syntax glitch we need to spot.

Comment: In a UNION, you must return the same columns in every SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

In a [UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#set_operators) all queries need to be the same number of columns.

You need to post the schema of all tables. But according to the error message you posted, this could help for the 2 first tables:

```sql
SELECT *, null FROM `table_1` -- assuming table_1 has 10 columns, add 1 more empty to match the table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table_2` -- assuming table_2 has 11 columns
-- make the same to the rest of queries
-- UNION ALL
-- SELECT * FROM   `table_3`
-- UNION ALL
-- SELECT * FROM   `table_4`
-- UNION ALL
-- SELECT * , null, FROM   `table_5`
```

Update:

Adding a example of union all declaring the columns:

```sql
SELECT 
 col1_str,
 col2_str,
 col3_int,
 col4_int
FROM `table_1`
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 col2_str,
 FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", col1_date) as col1_str, -- transform a date column to string
 col3_int,
 null
FROM `table_2`
```

Comment: Schema :Account STRING NULLABLE 
Campaign_name STRING NULLABLE 
Date STRING NULLABLE 
Ad_set_name STRING NULLABLE 
Ad_name STRING NULLABLE 
Impressions INTEGER NULLABLE 
Cost__GBP_ FLOAT NULLABLE 
Link_clicks FLOAT NULLABLE 
Reach FLOAT NULLABLE 
Website_conversions FLOAT NULLABLE 
f0_ DATE NULLABLE

Comment: I have tried to edit the schema for the date field from string to date value but I have created another column instead called f0. Is there any chance I could just overwrite the schema of the existing date field from 'String' to 'Date' value?

Comment: You can specify the columns names instead of use the wildcard `* `. I will update the answer with an example.